# Remove Static references of Iron Python in wpf C# code

Tags: c#, python, .net, wpf, ironpython

I use the DLLs IronPython.dll and IronPython.Wpf.dll for running Iron Python in C# code using ScriptEngine and ScriptScope

I am running Iron Python script from the WPF c# code as

```
public static ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
public static ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

ScriptSource source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(Path.Combine(currentPath, temp), Encoding.ASCII, SourceCodeKind.File);
source.Execute(scope);
```

The script in the Source file has several methods and could be called as

```
Func<object> func = scope.GetVariable("scriptMethodName");
func();
```

I found that even after closing the application, there is still some memory not released and found in the diagnostic tool the following item

```
IronPython.Runtime.CodeContext <0x2890FCC> [Static variable temp$2.$constant1]
```

The static variables of the IronPython runtime still hold some memory as given in https://github.com/IronLanguages/main/pull/1250. This actually causes many bigger objects to still stay in memory

Is there any fix for this ?

I tried the following, but no improvement in fixing this

I included the options dictionary to

```
Dictionary<string, object> options = new Dictionary<string, object>();
options["Debug"] = true;
options["LightweightScopes"] = true;
```

Also tried

```
engine.Runtime.Shutdown();
scope.Engine.Runtime.Shutdown();
```

This issue is causing heavy memory leak,Is there a possibility to get hold of the memory used by the mainwindow and clear it explicitly

Comment: Looks like [there hasn't been a release](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IronPython) since that fix was committed.